# What is the exact relation of Hela to others?

Tags: character, marvel-cinematic-universe, thor-ragnarok

In *Thor: Ragnarok*, is Hela supposed to be Thor's full sister i.e. Odin's AND Frigga's daughter?

Or just Odin's?

Comment: The Wikia (unconfirmed) indicates that she is the daughter of Odin & Frigga - http://marvelcinematicuniverse.wikia.com/wiki/Hela

Comment: So then Loki and Hella's shared characteristics come from being raised by Frigga and taking after her magic gifts i.e producing the knives on queue, conjuring a headdress? Her looking far more similar to Loki than any other family member is strange, Loki would have been adopted after her imprisonment so he couldn't have deliberately tried to look like her.

Comment: She looks like Loki because her appearance is **comic book based** and [in the comics she's Loki's *daughter*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hela_(comics)).

Comment: Yes, I know their comic link, but since it's different in the movie and they haven't the same father I wondered if they may have the same mother as a way to account for their similarities.

Comment: Do you want to know only from the movie? Or Norse mythology also?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hela is officially Odin's daughter and Thor's older sister. She was born before Thor and was Odin's heir before he banished her. Hela is also Loki's older adopted sister.

As to whether Hela is Frigga and Odin's daughter, it's left for debate and on [her Marvel Cinematic Universe wiki page](http://marvelcinematicuniverse.wikia.com/wiki/Hela), it only states she is Frigga's possible daughter:

> **Relationships**
>
> Family
>
> Asgardian Royal Family
>
> Buri † - Great-grandfather
>
> Bor † - Grandfather
>
> Odin † - Father and Enemy
>
> **Frigga † - Possible Mother**
>
> Thor - Brother, Enemy and Attempted Victim
>
> Loki - Adoptive Brother, Enemy and Attempted Victim

Furthermore on her page, it states only that she is the daughter of Odin Borson:

> **The oldest child of Odin Borson**, Hela had served as her father's personal executioner and the leader of the Einherjar, helping him Conquer the Nine Realms through violence and war.

As far as we know, Frigga is Odin's only known consort and the question of Hela's mother has never been addressed or answered by any of the actors or directors. Nonetheless, Hela would be Frigga's daughter; it would just be the question of whether it's by marriage or blood.

## Update

**Spoilers for Avengers: Infinity War**

> Thor tells Gamora that Hela is his **half-sister**, confirming she is not the daughter of Frigga but only of Odin. Her MCU wikipedia page has changed Frigga's relational status to Hela from "Possible Mother" to **stepmother.**

Comment: According to comics, Frigga is not Thor's mother. It is not revealed to Thor that she is not his own mother.